# page navigation error with nav controller

Tags: navigation, ionic2

I downloaded ionic 2 project like

> ionic start myProj tabs --v2 --ts

i created a button and in ts page i made control for it

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@Component({

  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public nav: NavController) {
    this.nav = nav;
  }


  login(){
    console.log("login clicked");
    this.nav.push(HomePage);
  }

}
```

my html is

```
<ion-content padding>
    <button ion-button block (click)="login()" style="text-transform: none;">Login</button>
</ion-content>
```

when i run this i get an uncaught error

> main.js:55978 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../pages/home/home"

what is my problem could someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import is incorrect.

If you have placed `LoginPage` inside pages folder,

```
import { HomePage  } from '../home/home';
```

Comment: its my mistake now could u check the updated pic @suraj

Comment: change import path.. ../home/home

Comment: it worked could you explain it why i should not use ../pages/home/home

Comment: Its your path heirearchy.. Take a lookat your project structure..you had the wrong relative path

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan your `LoginPage` is in `pages/login/....` so when you call `../pages/home` from there, it will jump 1 directory back, thus, searching in `pages` so it tries to find `pages/pages/home`. But that doesn't exist. `pages/home` **does** exist. Either using that, or changing to `../../pages/home/home` if you want to keep the `pages` in your import.

Comment: i kept ..pages/home/home in app/module but in login ts i placed ../home/home and it worked @Ivaro18

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan yes I know but you requested an explanation :)